# Why do people use nested notation for modules rather than :: syntax?

Tags: ruby

To my eyes, this:

```
class Lifeforms::Animals::Person
  # stuff goes here
end
```

looks a lot more readable than this:

```
module Lifeforms
  module Animals
    class Person
      # stuff goes here but it's all indented
    end
  end
end
```

But it seems all the code I see uses the later way. Is there any particular reason for this? One concern would be that the modules might not be defined... but to me even this is better than the last example:

```
# Just make sure the modules exist
module Lifeforms
  module Animals
  end
end

class Lifeforms::Animals::Person
  # stuff goes here
  # and it doesn't all have to be deeply indented
end
```

Why do people do it the middle way? And am I the only one who thinks that the deep nesting makes the code much harder to read?

Comment: I don't think there is a definite answer to this. It is a matter of preference. I actually do have the same preference as you.

Comment: I thought it might be, but I still wonder how almost everyone (it seems) can prefer the nested way, when to me it's so much less readable. Thought I must be missing something.

Comment: @sawa Did you just downvote my answer just because I didn't accept your incorrect edit where you confuse what an expression evaluates to with what gets printed to stdout?

Comment: @stefan - sorry, that's a typo. I've fixed it.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I can parse the second - more verbose - syntax faster. It's instantly clear to me that `Person` is nested within two other modules. In the first example, I have to scan the class name for `::`, which takes a split second longer.

Comment: @Stefan As the class definition becomes shorter, your point becomes more effective, and as the class definition becomes longer, it is harder to keep track of how many closings by `end` is required, and the first form becomes easier to read. Maybe that is where the real answer lies.

Comment: By having them nested there is one fewer change that one must remember to make if any of the enclosing modules are renamed. @Stefan, yes, it's just you (scanning speed).

Comment: Skocik, you can ask why some anonymous person downvoted your question (though I believe it serves no purpose), but it's unfair and irresponsible to suggest who you suspect it was and (especially) their motivation for downvoting. In this particular case I'm quite sure you're wrong on at least one count. You should remove your comment and issue an apology to @sawa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree and I sometimes use the :: syntax. Note however that the semantics for constant resolution are different for the two syntaxes so they aren't exactly equivalent:

```
module A; module B; module C; end ;end ;end
module A; A_CONST=42; end

module A::B::C; puts A_CONST; end
#^ NameError: uninitialized constant A::B::C::A_CONST

module A
   module B
     module C
       puts A_CONST
     end  
   end  
 end  
#^ prints 42
```

Comment: Exactly, they are not equivalent, so they are not interchangeable. They have different lexical scopes, and constants are looked up first lexically, then by inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

If we take your example, and "flip" it:

```
module Lifeforms::Animals::Person
  # stuff goes here
  # and it doesn't all have to be deeply indented
end

module Lifeforms
  module Animals
  end
end
```

It fails with

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Lifeforms
```

"Nested" syntax defines module if it doesn't exist, but the "::" syntax relies on fact, that the modules exist.

Similar question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2869619/4381282).

Comment: This is equivalent to my first example - and I mentioned that the downside of that would be the modules might not be defined (ie, they'd give uninitialized constant error - I should've clarified that). The third example was merely a way of repeating the first example but ensuring the modules are defined.

Comment: So yes @joshua.paling - this is the thing. If you proceed with "nested" syntax, you are always safe. The module will be defined in case it is missing, where in case of "::" syntax, you'r relying on that, the modules were defined in any other place of application, which may turn is not that safe. To me, because it is safer option - this is why it is preferred way. If you checked the Rails code - they go with "nested" syntax. My apologies that it wasn't clear from my answer in first place. However I can see someone's answer is already approved, so everything is good! Good luck! :)