# Rails - proper way to create admin section (`module` or `Admin::`)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new in Ruby and RoR and I'd like to create an admin section for a demo app.

From a little research I've done I've found two different options for creating an admin section. Example:

```
# config/routes.rb
namespace :admin do
  resources :users
end

# app/controllers/admin_controller.rb
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authorized?
  ...
end
```

Which of the two options is the most proper way to define controllers for the admin section, or they are both equally same?

```
# app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb

# I think this is what rails generates if I run the "rails g controller admin::users" command  
class Admin::UsersController < AdminController
   ...
end

# or instead
module Admin
    class UsersController < AdminController
       ....
    end
end
```

Comment: I'd use an admin framework as per Navin's answer and save myself a shed-load of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approaches yield to the same result, which is an `UsersController` which inherits from `AdminController` and is found in the `Admin` module (namespace).

`Admin::MyClass` is just a shortcut for `module Admin ... class MyClass`, **but...**

I would however prefer the explicit nested code (with `module Admin` on its own line), because it does make a different if the `Admin`-module has never been defined before. This probably won't happen to you when hacking with standard rails, but can happen when you write ruby code outside of rails.

See these examples:

```
class I::Am::AClass
end

i = I::Am::AClass.new
puts i.inspect
```

will lead to

```
i.rb:1:in `<main>': uninitialized constant I (NameError)
```

if you never declared the `I` and nested `Am` modules before in your code.

Whereas

```
module I
  module Am
    class AClass
    end
  end
end

i = I::Am::AClass.new
puts i.inspect
```

will work:

```
#<I::Am::AClass:0x00000001d79898>
```

because the modules are created along the path to `AClass` (at least this is how I think about it).

If you ever run in that problem and want to save whitespaces (because you will usually indent stuff in a `module` definition), there are some idioms to use. The one that solves the problem in the most obvious way (again, to me) is the following:

```
# Predefine modules
module I ; module Am ; end ; end
# Just a shortcut for:
# module I
#   module Am
#   end
# end

class I::Am::AClass
end

i = I::Am::AClass.new
puts i.inspect

#<I::Am::AClass:0x000000024194a0>
```

Just found that the nature of your question (it is not about an Admin-Interface, more about Module-Syntax) is also nicely discussed here [Ruby (and Rails) nested module syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868835/ruby-and-rails-nested-module-syntax) . And I would love to see a ruby-bug report/feature-request on this :)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! just 2 more questions:
1. Should I use one of the administration frameworks like other users suggested, in general? In this case its a simple demo app, but I feel that a "custom" admin section feet much more into needs (I haven't tried any of these yet so I don't know how easily they can extend)
2. Just to confirm (in current demo app) in order to specify the different layout on the admin section, should I set `layout "admin"` inside my AdminController to work properly, right? the admin layout .erb file I suppose is placed in same location as the "public"?

Comment: In the meantime I learned to read the error messages :) From Rubys point of view we are speaking about Constants; whether class or module is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the administration framework for Ruby on Rails applications like

**ActiveAdmin** https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin

OR

**Railsadmin**
https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin

Comment: Right and good (consider including `administrate`, and ... this other gem), but does not answer the question.